# Laravel select where exists query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to create a query in laravel which will check if a username exists in the record where email equals $email. My table is called User.

I need this query because when a user registers, they only register with their email address and password and add a username at a later time, so I need to check if they have added a username yet.

I have checked the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries and can't understand which query I need to use, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

if (empty($user->username)) {
    // username is empty
} else {
    echo $user->username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like `$id = DB::table('user')->where('email', $email)->whereNotNull('username')->value('id');`. That will either return an id of the user that matches that email and does not have a username, or it will return null. Is that what you were asking for? If not can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to check existence without reading user data, the more efficient way is:

```
$exists=User::where('email', $email)->whereNotNull('username')->exists();
if ($exists) {
    //User exists. No other data about it.
}
```

To check it and read his data only if exists:

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->whereNotNull('username')->first();

if (!$user) {
    //Not found with username, maybe exists without it
}
```

To read it anyway and then check data:

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();

if (!$user->username) {
    //Does not exists even without username
}else if (!$user->username) {
    //Exists but without username
}else{
    //Exists with username
}
```